# Integrating Passkeys signCount 0

Tags: webauthn, password-less, ios16, passkey

I'm trying to implement passkey into my app. I am wondering if ASAuthorizationPublicKeyCredentialAssertion.rawAuthenticatorData supports signCount. It seems the value is always 0.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For security keys, this will contain whatever signCount the security key itself provided. For passkeys, signCount is not supported and will always be 0. That field isn't meaningful for a synced credential that can be used at any time from multiple devices. For easier implementation I would use [passkeys.com](https://passkeys.com) or read more at [apple.docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/public-private_key_authentication/supporting_passkeys)

Answer (score 0):

signCount will always be zero for multi-device credentials (passkeys).